# Azure DevOps custom task (in TypeScript): navigating through repository with file path and retrieving XML for future processing

Tags: javascript, typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-task-groups

As the title says, I’m working on a custom DevOps task that begins with navigating in the repository to an XML file from a file path. Then processes the XML file and saves the changes.

Now I’ve tried looking on google and through Microsoft’s own documentation. Where I found built-in tasks that do navigate the repo, retrieves an XML file, do stuff to it and save it. However, when looking at the task in GitHub, the pre-existing tasks rely on a library that is only internal and not available on npm.

Does anyone know how to retrieve an XML file from a file path in TypeScript?

Comment: What's kind of tasking are you developing with? Build, utility, test, package, deploy or others? Also would you mind sharing the built-in task you are found? For the retrieve an XML file from file path(local), you can refer the [read-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-xml).

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT Release task
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/ExtractFilesV1
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/FileTransformV1

Answer (score 0):

The [FileTransformV1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/FileTransformV1) you mentioned is using the [webdeployment-common-v2](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Common/webdeployment-common-v2) to replace the string in the xml or json file which is open source. And the [azure-pipelines-tasks project](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks) is under MIT License (MIT), you can develop with this source code if you agree it.

Another way is you can develop with [webdeployment-common](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdeployment-common) instead of version 2 since this package is already published to NPM site.

And if you also like webdeployment-common-v2 to be published, you can raise the feedback on the [azure-pipelines-task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks) GitHub.

Comment: Maybe you know how to answer this one as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68064726/how-to-get-an-external-file-path-in-an-azure-pipeline-task